# Matplotlib. How to use the same colors for plot each time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=[13, 8])
for x in range(10):
    labels = pred_labels[:len(predict)]
    plt.scatter(tnse[:, 0][labels == x], tnse[:, 1][labels == x], label=x)
plt.legend(fontsize='large')
plt.title('MNIST predictions')
plt.show()
```

I have `predict` - the maxtrix which is neural network output and `pred_label` which is vector of numbers `[0..9]`

The code should plot something like that:
[image: scatter]

And it does, but each group of dots has different color each time I want to plot them. Is there a way to make them have a constant color?

I tried to use this:

```py
plt.scatter(tnse[:, 0][labels == x], tnse[:, 1][labels == x], label=x, c=x)
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that I often use :

- create `N` colors from a colormap,
- specify color to each plot.

Here is a minimal example inspired from yours :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
from numpy import random, linspace

# datas
x, y = [], []
for _ in range(10):
    x.append(random.rand() + .1 * random.rand(32))
    y.append(random.rand() + .1 * random.rand(32))

# colors
colors = pp.cm.plasma(linspace(0, 1, 10))

# plot
pp.close(0)
pp.figure(0)
for color, i in zip(colors, range(10)):
    pp.plot(x[i], y[i], 'o', label=f"{i}", mec=color, mfc=color)
pp.legend()
pp.show()
```

that outputs:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools to cycle over 10 colors (giving the same color to each class every time you run it). Just replace `colors` with your colors to cycle

```py
import itertools

colors = itertools.cycle([colors])
plt.scatter(tnse[:, 0][labels == x], tnse[:, 1][labels == x], label=x, color=next(colors))
```

EDIT: According to comment below

Comment: This case they will be all red. Colors should be different for all classes, but the same for each plot